# java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException when reading a file

Tags: java

I want to read file content using this code:

```
String content = new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get("/sys/devices/virtual/dmi/id/chassis_serial")));
```

On some systems this file is not present or it's empty. How I catch this exception? I want to print message "No file" when there is no file and there is no value.

Comment: Use try-catch (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/try.html)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Create a `File` object and check if it exists.
If it does then it's safe to convert that file to a byte array and check that the size is greater then 0. If it is convert it to a String. I added some sample code below.

```
File myFile = new File("/sys/devices/virtual/dmi/id/chassis_serial");
byte[] fileBytes; 
String content = "";
if(myFile.exists()) {
    fileBytes = File.readAllBytes(myfile.toPath);
    if(fileBytes.length > 0) content = new String(fileBytes);
    else System.out.println("No file");
else System.out.println("No file");
```

I know it's not the one liner you were looking for. Another option is just to do

```
try {
    String content = new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get("/sys/devices/virtual/dmi/id/chassis_serial")));
} catch(Exception e) {
    System.out.print("No file exists");
}
```

Read up on try catch blocks [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/try.html) like MrTux suggested, as well as java `File`s and java io [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/).

Comment: Evil, evil, evil.  Don't catch `Exception`! Catch the exceptions that you expect to be thrown.

Comment: The existence check is just a waste of time. Opening the file has to do that anyway.

Comment: You are absolutely right Stephen C. My try/catch answer was the epitome of laziness.

Answer (score 2):

The `AccessDeniedException` can be thrown only when using the **new file API**. Use an `inputStream` to open a stream from the source file so that you could catch that exception.

Try with this code :

```
try 
 {
  final InputStream in = new Files.newInputStream(Path.get("/sys/devices/virtual/dmi/id/chassis_serial"));
 } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
   System.out.print("File not found");
 } catch(AccessDeniedException e) {
   System.out.print("File access denied");
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use filter `file.canRead())` to avoid any access exceptions.